# How to slice dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
0   a
1   b
.   .
.   .
49  aa
50  ab
51  ac
```

How can i get index [49] and [50] using slicing,
this is my code but index [51] also taken. i need slicing by ascending but without last index.

```
df[-3:]
```

thank you for your help guys

Comment: Try `df[-3:-1]`